# Existing function as a callback for Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

Weird behavior for this piece of code:

I have some Angular controller:

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'CrawlServerExecutor', function ($scope, CrawlServerExecutor) {

    $scope.results = [];

    var showResults = function (results) {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            $scope.results.push(result);
        });
    };
```

When writing it like this:

```
    var showResults = function (results) {
        results.forEach($scope.results.push);
    };
```

I get this error:
`Error: undefined is not an object` for trying to access the `push` function, I looked `$scope.results` inside the debugger and the object was recognized as an array, but for some reason in this syntax it does not refer to it's `push` function. and I like this code better because it's more elegant.

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried binding the array to the function (so when it's called, ``this`` will be correctly set) as in ``results.forEach($scope.results.push.bind($scope.results));``

Comment: @AlexCorreiaSantos - you're correct of course. Why not post an answer?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to test and just trying to figure out from the top of my head, so I didn't want to give a false answer. Glad it worked (I've added it as an answer)

Comment: Does `showResults` gets called repeatedly? Are the results aggregated, or replaced? And is the parameter (`results`) an array of array-like object?

Comment: It's an array, I call the function showResults().

Comment: Wouldn't undefined not have the method forEach then?

Comment: But is `showResults` called more then once, such that `$scope.results` gradually grows?

Comment: Nope, it should be called once.

Comment: Then why not simply assign the value to the property, like: `$scope.results = results;`?

Comment: @Amit that's what I've done eventually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the array to the function, so it can be called in the right context (`this` set properly).

```
results.forEach($scope.results.push.bind($scope.results));
```

Comment: This results in this error:
`Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.`

Comment: If you call the function multiple times with the same values, then you can clear the list before inserting as a quick fix ``$scope.results = []``, then proceed to do the ``forEach``

Comment: @johni: It is another story, the answer is correct, you can accept the answer and ask new question in SO. By the way, I suggest to downvoter to comment its downvote.

Answer (score 0):

In the latter notation you pass the reference of the push function. Therefore inside of the push function itself (which is some defined javascript-code) the "this"-reference will be "window".
This is what happens if you call a function without any bound context.
In the first case you call $scope.results.push(result), hence the context (and therefore the "this"-reference inside the push function) will be the $scope.results array.
In javaScript "this" can change depending on the context.

The problem now is that the push function of the Array-Prototype assumes that the context will be the array itself, which isn't the case here.

So what you can do is "bind" a specific context to a naked function with the "bind" method.

So you can try

```
results.forEach ($scope.results.push.bind($scope.results));
```

now the context (this variable) in the push function will be the array $scope.results again and the function will work properly

Answer (score 0):

You get an exception because when `push` (which is the function `Array.prototype.push`) is called, it's being called without context, without any `this` value to operate on.
Doing so is like calling it on an `undefined` value which is what the error message is telling you...

What your basically doing is concatenating 2 arrays and keeping the end result.

You don't need to iterate the array yourself to do that.

You can simplify your code with:

```
$scope.results = $scope.results.contact(results);
```

Or, if you prefer an "in place mutation" of `$scope.results`, try:

```
[].push.apply($scope.results, results);
```

Or, if you really want to iterate yourself and use `forEach`, use the last parameter to pass the `this` context:

```
results.forEach($scope.results.push, $scope.results);
```